# Finding Extreme Points

Tags: functional-analysis

I am working on understanding extreme points better and was wondering how one would go about finding the extreme points of the ball$(L^\infty(\partial\mathbb{D}))$?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$, the extreme points of the unit ball of $L^\infty(\mu)$ are the measurable functions $f$ with $|f| = 1$ almost everywhere.

Hints:

If $g \ne h$, there is a set of positive measure on which $|g - h| > \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, and then $|(g+h)/2|$ can be bounded away from $1$ there using the parallelogram law.

Conversely, if $|f| < 1 - \epsilon$ on a set of positive measure, add and subtract $\epsilon$ on that set to get two members of the unit ball whose average is $f$.